# Using Azure Storage Tables as Queues with multiple Worker Roles processing it?

Tags: architecture, azure, azure-storage

My application will be receiving 1000+ requests/transactions every second, via multiple instances of the Web Role. These roles will write a record for every transaction across  multiple Storage Tables (randomly, to spread Azure's 500 transactions/sec limit). Now, I need a reliable way to process/aggregate this data using multiple Worker Roles and write the results to my SQL database. AKA, this needs to scale horizontally.

I need to retain/archive all of the transactions in the Storage tables post-processing, so I could go with having one set of tables for queues, and when they are processed move them onto the archive tables, or perhaps there is a way to do this on a single table, not sure.

What would you recommend as far as a mechanism to distribute the current workload in these queues across my Work Roles? Obviously, each role has to be aware of what every other role is working on, so they only work on unclaimed transactions. I think each role will be retrieving 1000 records from the queue as a single work load and multiple worker roles could be working on the same queue.

Should I keep the Worker Roles "state" in a Cache, perhaps in SQL server.

Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you use a proper queue service to implement this feature instead of trying to implement queueing over the table service. This way you won't have to implement complex logic to know which records have been processed (logic that becomes difficult when you consider fault tolerance and possible errors, especially in a service such as Table Storage that has a very limited transaction capability). Trying to coordinate multiple workers reliably, accounting for all possible failure scenarios, and being scalable at the same time is something I wouldn't attempt at application level.

For instance:

1. The web role receives a request that represents a transaction;
2. The web role writes data to several tables;
3. The web role sends a message to the queue service representing the transaction with some unique ID (for instance the request ID, if there isn't another suitable primary key).
4. The worker role pulls messages from the queue.
5. For each message the worker role retrieves the set of objects from the table storage corresponding to the unique identifier of the message.
6. The worker role aggregates data as needed and writes it to SQL Database.

Notes:

1. Use either the Queue Service (from Storage) or Service Bus queues.
2. Spread the load among many queues for scalability.
3. Be sure to apply proper handling at all levels to account for transient failures.
4. Deal with the possibility of processing the same message more than once (the processing should be idempotent).

Comment: Thanks for your input Fernando! So if I go with the Azure Storage Queue (multiple queues) and have a farm of worker roles retrieving the items one by one, wouldn't that be kind of slow, assuming I would like to get at least 1000 items from the queue on each run. Also, If I have multiple worker roles how can I account for the idempotent processing in this scenario?

Comment: I think Fernando's point was that you'd get one message from the queue, then retrieve the 1000 related items from table storage so getting messages from the queue will be very quick as it's only a small request and one request to table storage (storing all of the related items in one blob might be an option as well if it's efficient to write them that way).  Being idempotent is about being able to process the same data twice and still getting the same result.  How this affects you will depend on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @enlightenedOne, knightpfhor's comment is correct. I mean that you can store one message representing a whole "transaction" or command that may involve many records to be processed. It is also true that for efficiency you can retrieve multiple messages on the workers at the same time and distribute them to several threads. Finally, by idempotency I mean your message processing logic have to be prepared to receive the same message more than once, possibly just ignoring duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Fernando. Please take a look at [my blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2012/12/27/scalable-distributed-workload-with-azure-queues.aspx) on this very topic; it has to do with large scale processing of Azure Queues. This is based on a project I did with higher throughput requirements than the ones you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Fernando too. GetMessages method in the Queue Service API enables de-queuing the specified number of messages in a single transaction. If de-queuing logic is implemented right, you may not have to worry about processing being idempotent, however it will make your solution more robust.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the following approach based loosely on CQRS.

The web role validates the transaction and writes it to one or more queues. (You may need to write in random or round robin fashion to more than one queue, if you hit queue limitations.)
Note, a queue is merely a conduit or pipe to de-couple your web roles from the worker roles and the format of the message does not really matter. I would try modeling the transaction as an object and serializing it to get the queue message.  If a transition is too large to be written as a queue message you could write to table or blob storage and reference that resource in your queue message.

The worker roles, poll the one or more queues (randomly or in round robin fashion) and process the transactions, writing to SQL and/or table storage as necessary.

The rational of this architecture allows independent scaling of the web and worker roles and reduces dependencies between them. The web role only needs to know how to validate and serialize the transaction and not about how to persist or process the transaction.

For higher throughput on the worker role side, message can be pulled out and processed in parallel. Azure queue guarantee that a single message is will retrieved by only one client at a time, (unless visibility timed out). You can support idempotency, by assuming that the message could have been processed earlier in part or completely.